# Matlab / R and Ethereum integration

Tags: oracles

What is the most efficient integration of off-chain tools like **Matlab** or **R** into Ethereum? (in order to do off-chain calculations and reduce gas costs)

Comment: There is in fact an answer to this, unfortunately the moderators chose to close this. Oraclize provides an off-chain auditable computation query service, which allows you to containerize via docker and run computations which depend on external libraries, or are just not feasible on the EVM, off-chain.

Please have a look at this example, which will show you the result directly in the browser, on the Oraclize icon tab - [Computation Example](https://goo.gl/5GGWsm)

Refer to [our documentation](https://goo.gl/0Ti5BS) for further info.

Comment: Hi Thomas, this is exactly what I was hoping for. Perfect, I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Great! If you find any issue while testing it, feel free to write here or in our gitter support channel ( http://gitter.im/oraclize/ethereum-api ). We would be happy to help!